# programs migration from pthread (posix) to openmpi

Tags: c++, posix, mpi

I have a system using POSIX compiling my programs with g++, but, I got an opportunity to access a big machine that has multiple processors and it has to modules mvapich2 and openmpi, So, i think that openmpi should be the correct one to be migrated my system.
The problem is that I don't have to much experience in openmpi, and i don't know how to migrate my programs to this new environment.

Reading a little bit i think i have to use the MPI functions to do my system working in this environment and change the POSIX functions?.

In this section i am calling the pthread functions to handle threads which i think are common instructions.

```
Thread::Thread( PFUNC func, void * arg )
{
        pthread_detach( pthread_self() );
        pthread_attr_t attr;
        pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
        int s = pthread_create( &xThreadId, &attr, func, arg);
    if (s != 0)
            throw EXCEPT_NOTHREAD;

       pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
       pthread_detach( pthread_self() ); 

}
```

my system works as well with semaphore, mutex, i need to replace as well the use of semaphores and mutex? how?. Please advise how to approach this, if i really need to change my programs or there is a trick avoid to change my programs and run it in openmpi environment.

thanks a lot

Comment: No, you need to severely change your program to use the MPI set of functions rather than pthreads. The only answer I can give here is to go and have a look at the MPI reference, there isn't a magic bullet.

Comment: thanks. any document explaining how can do that?

Comment: The most fundamental difference between MPI and threads is that with MPI data is explicitly passed as messages between entities with separate memory spaces (distributed memory) while threads share their memory (shared memory). This might require huge changes to the data structures and the algorithms in your program in order to make them more suitable for the distributed storage, e.g. to minimise the number/volume of messages passed around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going from a multi-threaded program to a parallel MPI program is not a trivial task you will have to learn MPI and there may be no way around this.

I would start with basic MPI examples there are plenty found with a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=mpi+examples&oq=mpi+examples&gs_l=hp.3..0l3.687.2066.0.2422.12.10.0.2.2.0.193.1039.5j5.10.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.3.psy-ab.AEXMBeF4MlY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42553238,d.dmQ&fp=80231a349c1608&biw=1024&bih=684)

and also I would recommend to refer to the documentation for you MPI implementation (you mentioned [openmpi](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/)) and also refer to the [MPI standard documentation](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/docs.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will really appreaciate if you have any site where i can find the difference between these two approaches. thanks.